# HTML Javascript Slideshow Optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had to write my own code of a couple of lines for displaying slideshow on my websites splashpage. I couldnt use any plugin as I had designed the website on HTML5 and css3 and images were synchronized to resize with the browser. Now, coming to the actual problem, the last image takes double time as taken by 
each image in the list. Below is the HTML and the javascript pasted.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="backgrounds">
    <div class="bgs" style="z-index:1000;">
        <!--<p style="z-index:999; margin:0; margin-top:300px; color:red; position:absolute;">Let the Feeling Wrap Around</p>--> 
        <img src="images/main_nop.jpg" alt="" class="background" />
    </div>

    <div class="bgs" style="z-index:999; display: none">
        <!--<p style="z-index:999; margin:0; margin-top:300px; color:red; position:absolute;">Let the Feeling Wrap Around</p>--> 
        <img src="images/main_jkl.jpg" alt="" class="background" />
    </div>

    <div class="bgs" style="z-index:998; display: none">
        <!--<p style="z-index:999; margin:0; margin-top:300px; color:red; position:absolute;">Let the Feeling Wrap Around</p>--> 
        <img src="images/main_ghi.jpg" alt="" class="background" />
    </div>

    <div class="bgs" style="z-index:997; display: none">
        <!--<p style="z-index:999; margin:0; margin-top:300px; color:red; position:absolute;">Let the Feeling Wrap Around</p>--> 
        <img src="images/main_def.jpg" alt="" class="background" />
    </div>

    <div class="bgs" style="z-index:996; display: none">
        <!--<p style="z-index:999; margin:0; margin-top:300px; color:red; position:absolute;">Let the Feeling Wrap Around</p>--> 
        <img src="images/main_abc.jpg" alt="" class="background" /> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    var count = 0;
    var repeatCount = 0;
    var backgrounds = $('.bgs').length;
    function startSlideShow() {
        myRecFunc = setInterval(function () {
            if (count == backgrounds) {
                $('.bgs').eq(0).stop(true, true).hide(1000, 'easeOutExpo');
                $('.bgs').eq(backgrounds - 1).show(1000, 'easeOutExpo');
            }
            if (count < backgrounds) {
                $('.bgs').eq(count).stop(true, true).show(1000, 'easeOutExpo');
                $('.bgs').eq(count - 1).stop(true, true).hide(1000, 'easeOutExpo');
                count++;
            }
            else {
                count = 0;
                repeatCount++;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    startSlideShow();
```

The first if() in the code above is the one I added to handle the situation I stated on top, thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hope you realize that you can condense your conditional logic into a single if and else if instead of two ifs _and_ an else.

Comment: Can you post any sample with the issue? (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I cant post it with actual images from the client, and making temp images will take time, the issue is just that the last image takes double time.

Comment: and the javascript code is not optimized, will see for that in the end, had to finish this on urgent basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a condition where you do nothing for a whole interval which is your "else" case.  Try moving that check inside so that it happens immediately.

```
var count = 0;
var repeatCount = 0;
var backgrounds = $('.bgs').length;
function startSlideShow() {
    myRecFunc = setInterval(function () {
        $('.bgs').eq(count).stop(true, true).show(1000, 'easeOutExpo');
        $('.bgs').eq(count - 1).stop(true, true).hide(1000, 'easeOutExpo');
        count++;
        if (count === backgrounds) {
            count = 0;
            repeatCount++;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
startSlideShow();​
```

Comment: Also, assign `$('.bgs')` to a variable. Or, better, assign an id to the element and do the select by it. Selection by class is quite slow, especially in HTML pages with large number of elements. Also move the select outside of the function that is called by `setInterval`.